# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fresh installation does not detect Ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, ethernet, intel

lshw -C network sees the card correctly as Intel 82566DM-2 ID:19 but ifconfig -a sees no interface, nothing.  Worked fine with earlier Ubuntu before installation.  Do I need a specialist driver or can I get it working with the present installation without specialised driver?  I installed on a Lenovo desktop Think Centre M6072-ADM and also on an older Lenovo model which recognised the Intel on board ethernet card perfectly in installation.  The working machine has an Intel 82573e adapter so it appears the 82566DM-2 is problematic.  Note Windows 10 did not like this ethernet card either but previous distributions of Ubuntu were OK.

Because I lost wired connection I plugged in my Asus N12 usb wireless card which worked immediately with 16.04.  With earlier releases I had to manually install a driver however once running its performance was fantastic reporting 240MB/sec and would run of months without going down.
The same N12 USB wifi will now only show average of 54MB/sec and the performance on video is noticeably lower quality.  Does anyone know why the performance of the N12 has deteriorated so much?  Should I just remake the driver I used with 10.04 to recover performance?

If I can get the wired connection running I will not need to use the N12 but thought it worth reporting the performance drop in any case

Answer (score 0):

We have run into a similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04. Essentially, DHCP requests are coming across with a bogus MAC address when it PXE boots. Our testing has confirmed that the issue is with the E1000/E1000E (PCI/PCIe) driver. We were able to confirm this by using an older Kernel from the 2.6 tree. [This article](https://lwn.net/Articles/278016/) from 2008 explains the history of the driver. Currently the kernel has the E1000E driver compiled in and there is blacklisting in the E1000 that prevents it from loading for this chipset (and others). In short, the kernel is compiled so that it forces the E1000E driver to load for the Intel 82566DM-2 and it does not work (sometimes?). Our situation is more complex. But, for your case, I believe the easiest solution would be to compile your kernel with E1000 support only. Do not include E1000E support and you should (theoretically) be okay.

Comment: You say "to compile your kernel with E1000 support only." Then you say "Do not include E1000 support". Which should be done? Also, how is that done?

Comment: Hello JohnThanks for the additional information, most appreciatd.

Comment: Typo: It should have said "Do not include E1000E support". I edited to correct this.